# What causes long-term RTD reading drifts?

Tags: pcb, error, rtd

I am working with a controller that was designed to read multiple types of inputs including 3 wire RTD signals.

In some cases, we have observed the controller suddenly spike up +15 degrees and sustain that temperature reading for a long period of time; that is, until someone touches the plastic connector plugs inside the controller.

This is the first time I've heard of a long-term error like this, and touching non-conductive plastic connectors doesn't seem like it would effect the RTD circuit.

This only happens at certain locations, so we don't believe it's 100% a circuit design issue, but moreso a noise / wiring issue.

We had many of the original design's input circuitry have our sensor processor IC lose its programming and cease to function. This was due to suspected noise from high-voltage / high-frequency equipment (compressor fans / motors) ran near the controller. We improved the input protection by adding protection diodes and additional ground connections. We also changed the input voltage reference to 4.75 V from 15V, and removed the ferrite from the input reference and removed ferrite from the paths to the signal gnd. The signal ground is a floating ground layer of copper in the controller not connected to the incoming AC Earth connection.

The controller is powered with 120/24 VAC, and has a switching transformer that provides a 4.75 V DC power line to the analog input card for the RTDs. The output of the RTD IC is 4.096V.

The biggest mystery is that the temperature swings out, then never corrects itself. We have many explanations as to why the temperature would swing, but the IC we use has automatic calibration and our firmware should have a filter that compensates for any noise. However, the unit will show a temperature 15-20 degrees high, and won't correct itself until somebody touches their finger to the plastic connector plugs.

Any ideas without diving too much into the circuitry?

Comment: Two wire RTDs are subject to errors caused by wire and contact resistance in the path. Three wire ones rely on symmetry of the current path to offset the error on both sides by the error signal on one side, so there's still the potential for a high resistance connection to cause erroneous (always higher) readings. Touching the connector may jog the contacts enough for the connection to improve.

Comment: It's really only a light finger touch to correct the readings. We've also had it correct when a ribbon cable is lightly grazed along the input's board. It doesn't seem like a connection issue, since we're not pushing the plugs in much.

So the symmetry is the issue? We've had to jumper the return path for the sensor to signal GND before for other sensors to complete the circuit, and this might be the case with our RTDs as well.

Comment: Do you guys use contact lubricant?

Comment: Sometimes, but not in our RTD applications. We usually run the sensor to 22/3 for ~10 feet to the controller which connects to a plastic plug connector with screw terminals. I'd also add that this only happened when we replaced the RTD input circuitry with a new design, as the in the old design the processors were getting blown out.


Toor, any ideas with the contact lubricant?

Comment: Another possibility is your input amp is unstable, and is oscillating at some high frequency at times.

Comment: To educate the readers (and this person), can you post about the "getting blown out" input circuitry, and what was the energy source causing the damage?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I edited my post above with more information.

Comment: I read the "lightly touching" part again. Is it possible charge is building up in the floating lines (maybe the connector insulation itself from something in the air somehow?) with nowhere to go? You said the lines were floating and humans can't feel ESD until it is high enough. When the person touches the connector, does it work if they are wearing insulating gloves or use something insulating?

Comment: Yes, the lines are floating, and that's a major component we are re-evaluating. The biggest question is why touching the plastic wire terminals is correcting the temperatures so quickly, and if the hardware can be redesigned to prevent this from being a problem in the future. For what it's worth, we also have a plastic case with a capacitive touch screen on front, and touching the plastic corner screws  that connects the screen to the back of the unit has also caused the temperature to rapidly drop to the correct value (>15 degree swing!)

Comment: Do you know anything about the isolation method or floating supply used for those lines? Or something common about the air or dust in the problem locations?

Comment: The lines that have given us problems are usually unshielded, but we've received reports of it happening with shielded wires as well. Other lines would be a daisy-chain (usually unshielded) RS-485 CAT-5 connection running to all of the controllers and back to a central server room, usually 100s of feet. The dust shouldn't be an issue, as it's indoor at our problem spots. It may be humid, since our controller is also water-proof the controllers regularly get splashed with water in the setting they are in.